# Using a photosensor to control the dimmer on an LED

Tags: feedback

I've got a curious problem for all of you. I have a photosensor and a large LED array. The LED driver has analog control for intensity. I also have a function that correlates photosensor output to irradiance from the LED array.

We are currently using digital logic to control a DAC, but I would like to try an implement this with an analog circuit (and probably a DAC). The digital control basically works thusly;

1. Read the photosensor voltage
2. Compare that to the value that we know it should be for a given irradiance
3. If the photosensor voltage is too high, decrement the value of the DAC, if the photosensor voltage is too low, increment the value of the DAC
4. Rinse and repeat

This could probably be done with an FPGA, but I'm wondering if there is an analog circuit that could implement this. We'd need to set the DAC to our known value, which is fine. But we'd need a circuit to increase its output if Vphotosensor < Vdac and decrease it if Vphotosensor > Vdac. It goes without saying that a mere comparator would not give stable operation of the LED driver.

Our current system works, so it's fine if this isn't possible but an analog one would be more robust. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like an ideal application for a small MCU and (maybe) a digital photosensor.

Comment: You want to do it with an analogue circuit but want a DAC?  This is a classic analogue feedback circuit, especially as you have analogue input on your LED driver.  Why not post the details of that input and think about a pure analogue circuit?

Comment: Also: "large" LED array.  How big is that?  "Mere comparator" ... what kind of properties do you want it to have?  The problem is the same whether you have a digital or an analogue solution to it: you're thinking of some property of your system that you haven't described.  Is there a minimum on-time, for example?  Or some particular type of desired hysteresis behaviour?

Comment: We're currently using an MCU. I would like to get away from that. We had to design the photosensor ourselves, due to our application.

Comment: Yes. An analog circuit, but with a DAC. I have nothing against MCUs. I love them working with them, in fact. I don't love digital feedback, I much prefer the analog variety.

Comment: The LED array is about 400 W and is capable of irradiating up to 200 mW/cm^2. We have a function that correlates the photosensor voltage to the irradiance. For example, when the photosensor voltage is 1.2 V, we know that the irradiance is 100 mW/cm^2. When it is 2 V, we know that the irradiance is 150 mW/cm^2.

Comment: Let's say the user wants to irradiate the sample at 100 mW/cm^2. We know that the photosensor will read 1.2 V at this irradiance. The LED driver we're using has a voltage to current converter. For example 1 V at one of its pins will correspond to an LED current of 5 A, 2 V will correspond to an LED current of 10 A, and of course everything in between.

Comment: We don't know what LED current will correspond to the correct irradiance. We may have a good idea, but there are subtle variations between our LED arrays, not to mention the effects of aging, so accurately correlating a desired irradiance to an LED current is not practical.

Comment: However, the photosensor voltage will be directly proportional to the analog voltage used to control the LED current. In principle a comparator would, but in practice we would need the rise and fall times to be on the order of seconds, which is far slower than normal.